# How to capture only incoming TCP streams in WireShark?

Tags: filter, tcp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

How to capture only incoming TCP streams in WireShark?

(I would like to capture only HTTP connections to my web server, not any outgoing HTTP connections from applications.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on my test, 
1. You can use this capture filter for the WireShark that running on the server which you want monitor incoming packets:

```
dst host 10.58.123.456 and dst port 8080
```

2. And you can use following result filter to view traffic comes from certain client:

   ip.src_host == 10.78.123.456

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter like `(ip dst host 192.168.0.1 and tcp dst port 80) or (ip src host 192.168.0.1 and tcp src port 80)`.

Comment: Yes, I was using such display filter, but is there any better way?